# Inverting string components in file names

Tags: regex, shell, sed, rename

I'm trying to invert the components of the filename `foo@bar`.

This sed command does it on the string:

```
$ echo foo@bar | sed 's/\<\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)@\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\>/\2@\1/' 
  bar@foo
```

but passing the pattern to `rename` (prename AKA perl rename) does't result in the file being renamed (though the exit status is 0)

```
rename 's/\<\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)@\([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\>/\2@\1/' foo@bar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` and `perl` have very different regex syntax and features. This is what you might be looking for

```
$ rename -n 's/\b([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)\@([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)\b/$2\@$1/' foo@bar
rename(foo@bar, bar@foo)
```

- `\b` is word boundary
- `()` should not be escaped when capturing groups
- `$1`, `$2` are back-references in replacement section, not `\1`, `\2` etc
- `@` needs to be escaped, as it is used for arrays
- `-n` option is for dry run